# Can be a 'frequency funnel material' created?

Tags: solid-state-physics, photon-emission, solar-cells

Hello everybody and thank you for answering.

I have an idea in my mind since a while to raise the efficiency of solar panels, but It needs of a material with a very specific property. The material must be possible to rectify the frequency of the photons to a unique frequency. I imagine it as a frequency funnel. The sunlight arrives to the material and It converts high and low frequencies to a single middle frequency.

I think It could be possible 'playing' with the atomic levels and its decay rates, but I don't know if this is already done or if it's possible. I would appreciate if someone with knowledge of materials could enlighten me.

Thank you again!

Comment: You can filter. 2-photon mixing (high+low to get middle) is horribly inefficient, and would be tuned for a small range of high+low. And, buried in your question is a thermodynamic limit to closely consider. Bottom line, no, you can't do that with any efficiency. (Most efficient is probably a standard solar panel powering a semiconductor laser diode to power another "solar" panel.)

Comment: I discarded the 2-photon mixing for that reason, but i don't see the thermodynamic limit you are talking about. I try to figure it out with a 'game' of levels. For example, a low frequency photon could promote a carrier from a second level to a third, and then decay to a ground levell. Obviously, I need enough carriers in the second level, but the high energy photons make me the job by increasing the material's temperature, and then pumping carriers from the ground to the second level.

Comment: You need to consider detailed balance. Consider Einstein coefficients.

Comment: Right, I forgot about that. I will check it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Several companies have tried this. They were crushed by ever falling prices of polysilicon.

The easy way to do this is to get a fluorescent material. Fluorescence occurs when photons from a wide range of frequency are absorbed and then re-emitted at one strongly favoured frequency. However, this process is *generally* a "downconversion*, the output is a lower frequency than the input.

This is still very useful. For instance, most laundry detergents include a fluorescent dye, which absorbs UV light and re-emits it as blue light. This is why they're almost always blue. The blue light offsets the yellowish tint that old clothes get, and yellow + blue = white, so now your shirt looks white again.

In the case of solar panels, this only helps if your cells are *really* efficient at a particular frequency. In the case of silicon we're in luck, because that's true - silicon cells would work better if all the sunlight was red instead of a broad spectrum. Actually it's true for most solar cells, they will always be most efficient for light at a specific frequency.

Now this was a big idea when silicon was expensive. One idea, the "Slivr", used sheets of dyed plexiglass that glowed in red. They were arranged so light hit the plastic at an angle, so that it became trapped within the plastic (total internal reflection). As it bounced around it would eventually hit the dye and downconvert into red. There was a small number of cells on one end, so these small strip of cells got light from the entire plastic sheet.

Now this process is NOT that efficient. Some of the light goes right through the sheet, some reflects, a bunch is absorbed. But with the downconversion you're getting some of that back. And at the time, silicon was *way* expensive, so even though you might not be getting all the light you would if it was just a cell in direct sunlight, you're still getting a whole lot of light for the cost of a small cell.

The only thing is, it turns out you can make pSi for not much more than a sheet of dyed plexi! And so Slivr is no more. There was one in the US as well, same basic concept, but I don't recall their name.

Now the opposite process also occurs, *parametric upconversion*. This is *much* more difficult to arrange, and the cost of the things that do it are way out there. So no one does that, that I know of, for solar cells. They do use them in lasers though, because it's easy to make a powerful IR laser and then upconvert that to what you're looking for. The National Ignition Facility uses this to turn it's IR into UV, for instance.

**UPDATE:** Nope, SLIVR is another design, I have the names mixed up.

Comment: Thank you very much, your comment was very useful. The thing is, that by just doing downconversion you only gain in thermodynamic efficiency in the cell, but maybe the material could do two things, downconversion and upconversion at the same time. You gave me the example of fluorescents. In these kind of materials the difference in energy between the output photon and the input photon is 'wasted' to promote the atoms to another vibrational energy. But as the number of promoted atoms increases the chances to get downconversion increases aswell.

Comment: Do you think it's posisble to get both phenomena with reasonable efficiency?

Comment: @JoanLosa - no, the mechanisms are very different. If your ultimate goal is to improve the efficiency of solar, then a better solution is to downconvert and then use a semiconductor with your target frequency. For instance, PbS semis have a bandgap in the deep IR, so if you're trying to get the IR, use PbS and a different downconverter on top.

Comment: @JoanLosa - I just re-read your original comment on my answer, and I think you'll find the Wiki article on the Shockly-Quessier limit useful.

Comment: Thank you, I knew this limit but I forgot their name. I'm currently learning about Ramman lasers because they could make me the job. I've read that they work because of the Stokes Ramman scattering, but if  an important number of molecuales are excited there should be chances for anti-Stockes Ramman scattering to accur right?